Why are the pages on my Vite+React multi-page app defaulting to the homepage?
My React app should have 2 main webpages: localhost:3001/ and localhost:3001/tags/. The issue is that loading localhost:3001/tags/ will display the contents at localhost:3001/. I can also tell that /tags/ isn't loading properly because I set the page title for it to "Tags" but instead, "Homepage" shows as the page title.
The file structure:
.env
index.html
package.json
vite.config.ts
etc.
src/
  | App.tsx
  | main.tsx
  | tags/
    | index.html
    | tags.tsx

The main index.html has the script tag with src="/src/main.tsx". The src/tags/index.html is the same as the main index.html except with <title>Tags</title> and script tag with src="./tags.tsx".
tags.tsx has a simple "Hello world" inside the createRoot().
vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3001
  },
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: 'index.html',
        tags: 'src/tags/index.html'
      }
    }
  }
 })


Did you try going to http://localhost:3001/src/tags/index.html?

@isaacsan123 Wait... that worked, along with localhost:3001/src/tags/. Thanks! But what would be the necessary changes to get it working for localhost:3001/tags/?

Based on your comment, it seems like you just want to know how to not have to have src in the pathname.
For that, you need to do a little restructuring:

First of all, run npm i -D @types/node, so that you will properly get access to the path module within your vite config.  I couldn't use the path module properly until I did that.

Next, move your index.html file into your src folder.  This way, all your pages will be on the same level - relative to src, and you won't have to handle specific cases involving src.

Update the script tag src within your index.html to be src="./main.tsx".


Next, you just need to do a few small changes to your vite config.
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { resolve } from 'path';

const root = resolve(__dirname, 'src');

export default defineConfig({
  root,
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 3001
  },
  build: {
    outDir: resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    emptyOutDir: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: resolve(root, 'index.html'),
        tags: resolve(root, 'tags', 'index.html'),
      },
    },
  },
});


Whenever you want to add another page, just add it to the inputs here.  Using resolve with root always makes sure that the pages are relative to src, which means src won't show up in the url.

Thanks. I actually tried this earlier and it worked but I was unable to get the environment variable stored inside .env, which I read should stay in the root folder. Time to research how to get the vars from inside /src :)
